# randomly choose input entered, add to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am struggling to get it to work since this is my first try making something on my own.

I want to take input from the input field inside the form, click the submit button, and on each row i want a new input[type='text'] in a table.

for example: david, jan, mark

each of the above names needs to be added on a new row separetly,  randomly chosen, below each other

hope this makes sense.

in the example below, it adds the input next to each other.

```js
// when the page is loaded
// hiding the table in the DOM = document object model
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table').hide();
});

// Get input from 'inputNames' text area
$('#button').click(function() {
  var name = $('input[type="text"]').val().split(',');

  // checking to see if the "input[type='text']" value is empty
  if ($('#inputNames').val() !== '') {

    // iterate over de names
    $('#inputNames').each(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        name[i];
        //Create a new td add to tr
        $('.inserted').append('<td>' + name[i] + '</td>');
      }
    });


    // log the variable name to see the object
    console.log(name);

    // slide in the table
    $('.table').fadeIn(2500);

    // without it wont load the fadeIn effect
    return false;

  } else {
    alert('You need to fill in the input field');
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Roulatie Schema</title>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Roulatie Schema</h1>
      <p class="lead">Gewoon een simpel roulatie schema, waarbij alleen de namen van de betreffende mensen hoeft te worden ingevuld</p>
      <hr class="my-4">
      <form id="myForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputNames">Fill in the names separated by a comma</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNames" required='true' aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Example name, name">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">the field above can not be empty!!</small>
        </div>
        <button id="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <table class="table" align='center'>
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>#Rounds</th>
          <th>#First Round</th>
          <th>#Second Round</th>
          <th>#Third Round</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="inserted">
          <td>Luxe lades</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inserted">
          <td>Meta lades</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inserted">
          <td>Inpak</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inserted">
          <td>Controle 100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inserted">
          <td>Lades inhangen</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inserted">
          <td>Deuren</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inserted">
          <td>Planken</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inserted">
          <td>Panelen</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you post the form html as well?

Comment: Where’s the button? Also assign the click in the load handler too

Comment: @CodeAt30, added the form html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this answer has two steps, in the hope that I understood what you want to do correctly.

**Step #1:**

You are currently fishing the names properly but instead of adding them to the table in new rows you just add them as cells to each and every row. So changing the append() content can fix that:

```
$('#inputNames').each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        name[i];
        $('tbody').append('<tr class="inserted"><td>' + name[i] + '</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

**Step #2:**

Now you want them to be added randomly. There are many ways to go about this but I will just offer one, which in the code actually comes before the 1st step:
randomize the name array.

how? simple:

```
var name = $('input[type="text"]').val().split(',');
name.sort(function(a, b){return 0.5 - Math.random()});
```

notice you do not to set `name=name.sort()` the method already sets it for you.

Now the code takes the names, randomizes them, and appends them as new rows in the table.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, I can go from here thank you